# Complex Table with ROWSPAN

Tags: html

I have the following sample table:

```html
    <table border="1" align="right" width="200">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Main Category</td>
            <td>top right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bottom right</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

For the  **top right**, I like to create another column to the right of it with 3 rows called Right One, Right Two, Right Three.

For the **bottom right** I like to create so that there is another column to the right of it with 4 rows called Bottom One, Bottom Two, Bottom Three, Bottom Four.

I know I need to further use the rowspan but tried a number of things but I was not able to get it to work. 
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you displaying tabular data with that – or are you just trying to use this table for layout purposes? The latter you should not even start with.

Comment: Using table to format

Comment: you should put the table border, align and width in css not html, these tags are deprecated and not supported as of HTML5

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <table border="1" align="right" width="200">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Main Category</td>
            <td><table border=1 width=100%>
              <tr><td rowspan=3>Top Right</td><td>Right one</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Right two</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Right three</td></tr>
              </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><table border=1 width=100%>
              <tr><td rowspan=4>Bottom Right</td><td>Bottom one</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Bottom two</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Bottom three</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Bottom four</td></tr>
              </table></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```